# ActionHub (Mass Edit + Mass Update + Mass Delete) Lightning Customization?

Tags: lightning, javascript, appexchange, field-update

We are currently migrating from Classic to Lightning.  Our ActionHub Mass Edit + Mass Update + Mass Delete AppExchange package customizations rely on copy/paste of JavaScript for unincluded default objects defined in the package.  As we all know, JavaScript buttons are longer available in Lightning.

**Question:** Can I use the package Visual Force on custom objects, and if so how do I configure that?

**Specifics:** Specifically I need to be able to perform Mass Updates (by field) on the Contract object. Also open to other alternatives and AppExchange packages.

[image]

In the picture above I don't see any Visual Force page(s) available.